# Why does my ForEach loop only grabs last item in array?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, foreach, indexing, timeout

I want to perform a function for every item in my array, but it only triggers for the last item in the array and I'm not sure how to go about fixing this:

```
$scope.PlayMovie =function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.CamArr, function(value, index){
        $timeout($pyx.globe.camera(value.cam, 3000), 5000);
    });
};
```

Setting the globes camera takes a camera object and a time. So this will take 3 seconds to move to that location. I put that in a time out so it would wait for 2 seconds after it gets to the location then move onto the next location. This only seems to be grabbing the last index in my array though. I have asked for the count to be displayed when an camera object is added and the objects are making it into the array so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Play movie is being called on a button click.

Thanks in advance for any help. Let me know if you need some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, two things are going on:

1. This is evaluated immediately by the forEach loop, and you're setting a timeout for the function's return value:

   ```
   $pyx.globe.camera(value.cam, 3000)
   ```

   You probably wanted to do

   ```
   $timeout(function() { $pyx.globe.camera(value.cam, 3000) }, 5000);
   ```
2. Your foreach loop is setting up several timeouts which will all fire 5 seconds from now. It sounds like you want to fire one immediately (in 0 seconds), then one 5 seconds from now, then one 10 seconds from now, etc. Try multiplying the delay by the index (0, 1, 2, 3, etc), like this:

   ```
   $scope.PlayMovie = function() {
       angular.forEach($scope.CamArr, function(value, index){
           $timeout(function() { $pyx.globe.camera(value.cam, 3000) }, index * 5000);
       });
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning to the same value each time through the loop, so naturally you will end up with one call that has only the last value in the loop. Fix it by doing something like this:

```
$scope.PlayMovie =function(){
    var timeoutArray = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.CamArr, function(value, index){
        timeoutArray.push($timeout($pyx.globe.camera(value.cam, 3000), 5000));
    });
};
```

This should give you a different timeout each time, and a way to refer to them individually if you need to cancel one or more.